# TestNG not running @Test for Firefox Driver -- Chrome working

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am building Selenium WebDriver tests for Chrome and Firefox in Eclipse using TestNG. When I run the testng.xml file as a TestNG Suite, it opens the Firefox browser, but does not enter the @Test method in the class file. It does the @BeforeClass method just fine.

However, when I have virtually the same code but for Chrome, it works fine - it enters the @Test method and everything is golden.

Any idea why it would enter the @Test method for Chrome, but not Firefox?

Here is the code for my class:

```
public class TestFireFox {

    private WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        System.out.println("Running TestFireFox Class");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void verifySearchButton() {

        System.out.println("Inside Verify Method");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        String search_text = "Google Search";
        WebElement search_button = driver.findElement(By.name("btnK"));

        String text = search_button.getAttribute("value");

        Assert.assertEquals(text, search_text, "Text not found!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the order of statements. You need `setProperty` before instatiate `Firefox`.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```